# Using an array list

Tags: java

Which code snippet calculates the sum of all the elements in even positions in an array?

```
a) int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; < values.length; i+=2)
{
sum++;
}

b) int sum = 0
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
{
sum++;
}

c) int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < values.lengthl; i++)
{
sum +=values [i];
}

d) int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i + 2)
{
sum +=values [i];
}
```

are any of these correct? because for my answer I got

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i += 2)
{
sum +=values [i];
}
```

is my answer correct? or is it one of the multiple choices?

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and answer D?

Comment: my answer is  "values.length; i +=2"

for d its "values.length; i + 2)

Comment: Ah, I see. Are you sure that isn't a typo?

Comment: Why don't you run each in a unit test and see which gives the correct answer

Comment: yeah, my answer is correct right?

Comment: Looks correct. (depending on the definition of "is 0 a even position") and for potential integer overflows, of course. :)

Answer (score 1):

None of these answers appear to answer the question.  Here is a code snippet which will compute the sum of all even elements of array `values`.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i = i + 2) {
    sum +=values [i];
}
```

You have to increment the loop variable `i` by 2 in order to sum only even elements.  Also note that I assume the first **even** position is the **second** position in the array, which is `values[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

A small correction you are using array in your code. `ArrayList`  is different from `Array`. `ArrayList`  doesn't have a `length` property, it's the property of an `Array`. I think the answer added by **Tim Biegeieisen** is correct for an array.

Similary, You can do the same thing for a array list like this -

```
int count=0;
int sum=0;
for(Integer i : values){
   if(count%2==0){
      sum = sum+i;
   }
   count++;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

And here values is an `ArrayList` of `Integer`.  Note you can not put `int` or any other primitive type in `ArrayList`. So you may declare your `ArrayList` used here (that is `values`) like -

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Hope it will Help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A and B don't add elements of the array to `sum`; B and C process all elements.  So if any of them are correct, it must be D.  But since D does not change `i`, it cannot be right, either.